# Is there a way to judge what element is comes to when scrolls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ask if there is a way to judge an dom element by scrolling position, say, if I scrolled and I want to judge which element the scrollbar comes into in scroll container. The bootstrap scrollspy  seem to be perfect on most cases, but I still wonder how to judge an element by scroll position.
Anyone can help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "judge" in this context.

Comment: What do you mean by "judge"? do you want to know which elements are shown and which are hidden?

Comment: I guess you want to know which element the scroller is on or which element is being shown on the screen currently. You can have that thing by having a position absolute element on top of the page (hidden div) and by using the Jquery.nearest plugin can achieve the result by calling the .touching(); function of it. 
Try this link  http://gilmoreorless.github.io/jquery-nearest/
I have used the same plugin in few projects to get the on screen element.

Comment: [Scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) seems to be a plugin that examines the `scrollTop` and highlights menu items corresponding to an elememnt that's in the view to guide the user.